# How to set up apache server for public domain on linux?

Tags: apache-httpd, firewall, webserver, port-forwarding, domain

I am running Arch Linux on my computer.

**tl;dr** I have portforwarded apache and the router on port 80 and disabled all firewalls on my computer and router. Apache has started and started with no visible errors. Why can I not connect to the apache server with my public domain ip?

- I have port forward port 80 to my local address for this computer. I have installed `apache` via `pacman` and started the service.
- `systemctl` says there are no issues.
- `journalctl` reports no issues for apache, the configuration is the default and is configured to port 80.
- I have an index.html with text in `/var/www/html`, in `/etc/httpd/` and in `/srv/http`.
- My `httpd.conf` says the ServerRoot is in `/etc/httpd` and document root in `/srv/http`.
- I am listening on 127.0.0.1:80.
- I have disabled my router firewall and I have no active firewall on my linux computer.

Why when I go to my ip "12.345.67.890" there is no response or connection? How do I connect apache to the public domain?

Comment: You are only listening on 127.0.0.1?  What does the output of `ss -tlp | grep :80` return?

Comment: Nothing. Chaning to my local ip address returns nothing as well and the site is still inaccessible. Also I have given all directories mentioned the owner http.

Comment: (Stupid comment deleted). But still, you can check if port 80 is open with some tools online, google "check my port" or something like that.

Comment: Success: I can see your service on 12.345.67.890 on port (80)

Comment: `LISTEN                      0                           511                                                  127.0.0.1:http                                                      0.0.0.0:* `        is the only one that shows up, when I remove `| grep :80` Also the server runs locally at port 80 and opens the index.html file but not public

Comment: Please, add this information to your question, including the command you used to obtain it (comments are not meant to stay and aren't really readable). Also, is there anything useful in httpd's logs (they should be in `/var/log/httpd`)? Note that you need `ss -tln` to see ports as numbers - and be able to grep for them as e.g. `:80` (`-p` also shows processes, but it generally requires running as root to be useful).

Comment: Ah right, I forgot to use the syntax for `ss` that just gives port numbers. Your problem is that httpd is listening on the loop back address and not all interfaces (or the IP specifically) so there’s no way to reach it from outside of your computer.